# Session variable not getting passed to uploadify.php

Tags: php, session, upload, uploadify

I need to use a session variable for username to specify the upload path in uploadify (version 3.1). In uploadifive.php using the following works fine:

```
$uploadDir = 'media/' . $_SESSION["user_name"] . '/';
```

However in uploadify, when I use the same code, files are just uploaded to the media folder (ignoring the user folder). I have echoed $_SESSION["user_name"] in uploadify.php and retrieved this using the onUploadSuccess function, and indeed the username variable is not getting passed to uploadify.php, despite starting the session.

It seems strange that this would work with uploadifive and not uploadify. I am not too savvy with PHP and would be glad of some help with this.

I include the full uploadify.php script below.

Thanks,

Nick

```
<?php
session_start();
/*
Uploadify
Copyright (c) 2012 Reactive Apps, Ronnie Garcia
Released under the MIT License <http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php> 
*/
// Define a destination
$targetPath = 'media/' . $_SESSION["user_name"] . '/';

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetFile = $targetPath . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

    // Validate the file type
    $fileTypes = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'); // File extensions
    $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

    if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
        echo '1';
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid file type.';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you `var_dump( $_SESSION )` just to make sure you're actually storing data? I mean, you *did* set the value when they logged in, right?

Answer (score 2):

I've also stumbled upon this problem.

The Uploadify flash file is the one calling the PHP script, and not the browser, this means that the PHP Session isn't propagated from the browser to flash and to the the server, you only have to pass the session id by $_GET/$_POST to make the problem go away.

In the HTML file:

```
<input type="hidden" id="sessionid" value="<?php echo session_id(); ?>" />
```

In the javascript file:

```
$('#image').uploadify({
    'uploader'  : '/uploadify-v2.1.4/uploadify.swf',
    'script'    : '/uploadify.php',
    'cancelImg' : '/uploadify-v2.1.4/cancel.png',
    'folder'    : '/tempfiles',
    'auto'      : true,
    'multi'     : false,
    'scriptData': { 'session': $('#sessionid').val() }
});
```

In the PHP file:

```
if ( isset($_REQUEST['session']) && !empty($_REQUEST['session']) ) {
    session_id($_REQUEST['session']);
}
session_start();
```

There seems to be a problem when the session configuration is set to auto_start ( but I haven't fully tested this ).

And this is also mentioned in the [documentation of Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/using-sessions-with-uploadify/).

Comment: Thanks. I can now see that I missed the instructions on the uploadify site for [passing session variables](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/using-sessions-with-uploadify/) in version 3.x. I have implemented this and I am now getting an HTTP 500 error. formData is returning: `'formData' : { 'PHPSESSID' : '6670707f6671abcdfd8c06e2aaf079e6' },`, which looks OK. I am not sure what the error is related to. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Nick, about the 500 error, sorry can't help there, since I haven't encountered that error before with Uploadify, but check mod_security rules or disable it temporarily, just to see if it interferes with it or not, one time I had problems with Uploadify and mod_security, but the error code was 412 Precondition Failed.

Comment: Thanks.  I am trying to test whether the workaround for passing session variables is actually working, but I am not sure how to implement `var_dump( $_SESSION );` with uploadify.php. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735847/how-can-i-check-whether-session-variables-are-getting-passed-to-uploadify-php) for more info.  Any ideas?

Comment: Since it's giving 500 error, you can't see any response. I would try to comment out every line of code in the uploadify, and see if the error still exists, if it does, it's something in the configuration of the server that's making that error, if not it's something in the code.

Answer (score 1):

I would check your login script to make sure that you are indeed storing the username in the session array upon authenticating the user. You're calling `session_start()`, which eliminates that possibility, so if you're calling `$_SESSION["user_name"]` and *not* getting a value, it can only mean the value isn't there to begin with, or that you got the key wrong.

Comment: Thanks, the issue is due to a bug in Flash - the session cookie is not picked up by the Flash file.  There is a workaround detailed [here](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/using-sessions-with-uploadify/), which I wasn't aware of when I first posted the question above.  However I am now getting an HTTP 500 error on uploads.  formData is returning: `'formData' : { 'PHPSESSID' : '6670707f6671abcdfd8c06e2aaf079e6' },` and I am not sure if this should work with the code I have included at the top of uploadify.php as per the instruction in the workaround method.