# How can I check whether session variables are getting passed to uploadify.php?

Tags: php, session, uploadify

I am having some difficulty with the workaround method in uploadify (v3.1) for passing session data via the formData option. I have implemented the suggestion on [this page](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/using-sessions-with-uploadify/), but I am getting an HTTP 500 Error.

I am wondering how to check what is in my session, to see if the workaround is really working, i.e. if my session ID is really getting passed to uploadify.php. The usual method for returning variables echoed in uploadify.php is the onUploadSuccess event, but I can't use this, as uploads aren't completing successfully!

So I am wondering what other options I have.  I am aware of methods such as `var_dump( $_SESSION );` or `die(print($_SESSION));`, but I don't know where to look for the info these are returning.

I include the full uploadify.php script below, in case it is helpful.

Thanks,

Nick

```
<?php
$session_name = session_name();

if (!isset($_POST[$session_name])) {
    exit;
} else {
    session_id($_POST[$session_name]);
    session_start();
}

/*
Uploadify
Copyright (c) 2012 Reactive Apps, Ronnie Garcia
Released under the MIT License <http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php&gt; 
*/
// Define a destination
$targetPath = 'media/' . $_SESSION["user_name"] . '/';

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetFile = $targetPath . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

    // Validate the file type
    $fileTypes = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'); // File extensions
    $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

    if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
        echo '1';
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid file type.';
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: The `var_dump($_SESSION);` (or any other access to the `$_SESSION` array) needs to come after a valid session is present. A valid session is present after `session_start();`.

Comment: after `session_start();` add `var_dump( $_SESSION );`

Comment: Thanks.  I have included `var_dump( $_SESSION );` after `session_start();`, but I am not sure where to read what is returned.  uploadify.php is called by the uploadfify script on my index.php page, but even after uploadify.php is called, I see no dumping of variables on my index.php page!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `print_r($_SESSION)` as well, but `var_dump($_SESSION)` is useful too.

Remember, you only use after `session_start();`

Comment: Thanks, the issue is not how I am returning the session variables, but rather that I don't know where to look for them, i.e. I don't know where they are returned.  They aren't returned on my index.php page

Comment: Nothing appears when you put print_r or var_dump?

Comment: No, nothing appears.  I think it is something to do with the way uploadify.php is called by the uploadify script, though I am not too knowledgeable about PHP.  The usual method for returning variables in uploadify is to use the onUploadSuccess event as I mentioned in my question above, but as the issue I am having is that uploads are not successful I can't use this.

Comment: But what javascript do? He takes the targetPath in php and use this to upload?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be what is happening.

Comment: Did you try to put the `var_dump` or `print_r` inside the `if(!empty($_FILES))`